# Using C++20 chrono, how to compute various facts about a date

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, c++20

https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weekday.html computes various facts about a day of the year, for example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPWuO.png]

Given an arbitrary date, how can these numbers be computed with the [C++20 chrono specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/#time)?

Comment: _"... and we all know when ISO week 1 is, right? ..."_ -  "No, but I've got a library" ... :-) - Bravo Howard!

Comment: Image taken from https://stackoverflow.com/q/59391132/560648 (now deleted). Shame it was deleted as this ought to have been an answer to that question.

Comment: Correct.  I voted to reopen that one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is remarkably easy with the [C++20 chrono specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/#time).  Below I show a function which inputs an arbitrary date, and prints this information to `cout`.  Though at the time of this writing, the [C++20 chrono specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/#time) isn't yet shipping, it is approximated by a [free, open-source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  So you can experiment with it today, and even include it in shipping applications as long as you adopt C++11 or later.

This answer will take the form of a function:

```
void info(std::chrono::sys_days sd);
```

`sys_days` is a day-precision `time_point` in the `system_clock` family.  That means it is simply a count of days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  The type alias `sys_days` is new with C++20, but the underlying type has been available since C++11 (`time_point<system_clock, duration<int, ratio<86400>>>`).  If you use the [open-source C++20 preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), `sys_days` is in `namespace date`.

The code below assumes function-local:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
```

to reduce verbosity.  If you are experimenting with the [open-source C++20 preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), also assume:

```
using namespace date;
```

**Heading**

To output the first two lines is simple:

```
cout << format("{:%d %B %Y is a %A}\n", sd)
     << "\nAdditional facts\n";
```

Just take the date `sd` and use `format` with the familiar `strftime`/`put_time` flags to print out the date and text.  The [open-source C++20 preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) hasn't yet integrated the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), and so uses the slightly altered format string `"%d %B %Y is a %A\n"`.

This will output (for example):

```
26 December 2019 is a Thursday

Additional facts
```

**Common intermediate results computed once**

This section of the function is written last, because one doesn't yet know what computations will be needed multiple times.  But once you know, here is how to compute them:

```
year_month_day ymd = sd;
auto y = ymd.year();
auto m = ymd.month();
weekday wd{sd};
sys_days NewYears = y/1/1;
sys_days LastDayOfYear = y/12/31;
```

We will need the year and month fields of `sd`, and the `weekday` (day of the week).  It is efficient to compute them once and for all in this manner.  We will also need (multiple times) the first and last days of the current year.  It is hard to tell at this point, but it is efficient to store these values as type `sys_days` as their subsequent use is only with day-oriented arithmetic which `sys_days` is *very* efficient at (sub-nanosecond speeds).

**Fact 1:  day number of year, and number of days left in year**

```
auto dn = sd - NewYears + days{1};
auto dl = LastDayOfYear - sd;
cout << "* It is day number " << dn/days{1} << " of the year, "
     << dl/days{1} << " days left.\n";
```

This prints out the day number of the year, with January 1 being day 1, and then also prints out the number of days remaining in the year, not including `sd`.  The computation to do this is trivial.  Dividing each result by `days{1}` is a way to extract the number of days in `dn` and `dl` into an integral type for formatting purposes.

**Fact 2: Number of this weekday and total number of weekdays in year**

```
sys_days first_wd = y/1/wd[1];
sys_days last_wd = y/12/wd[last];
auto total_wd = (last_wd - first_wd)/weeks{1} + 1;
auto n_wd = (sd - first_wd)/weeks{1} + 1;
cout << format("* It is {:%A} number ", wd) << n_wd << " out of "
     << total_wd << format(" in {:%Y}.\n}", y);
```

`wd` is the day of the week (Monday thru Sunday) computed at the top of this article.  To perform this computation we first need the dates of the first and last `wd`'s in the year `y`.  `y/1/wd[1]` is the first `wd` in January, and `y/12/wd[last]` is the last `wd` in December.

The total number of `wd`s in the year is just the number of weeks between these two dates (plus 1).  The sub-expression `last_wd - first_wd` is the number of days between the two dates.  Dividing this result by 1 week results in an integral type holding the number of weeks between the two dates.

The week number is done the same way as the total number of weeks except one starts with the current day instead of the last `wd` of the year: `sd - first_wd`.

**Fact 3: Number of this weekday and total number of weekdays in month**

```
first_wd = y/m/wd[1];
last_wd = y/m/wd[last];
total_wd = (last_wd - first_wd)/weeks{1} + 1;
n_wd = (sd - first_wd)/weeks{1} + 1;
cout << format("* It is {:%A} number }", wd) << n_wd << " out of "
     << total_wd << format(" in {:%B %Y}.\n", y/m);
```

This works just like Fact 2, except we start with the first and last `wd`s of the year-month pair `y/m` instead of the entire year.

**Fact 4: Number of days in year**

```
auto total_days = LastDayOfYear - NewYears + days{1};
cout << format("* Year {:%Y} has ", y) << total_days/days{1} << " days.\n";
```

The code pretty much speaks for itself.

**Fact 5 Number of days in month**

```
total_days = sys_days{y/m/last} - sys_days{y/m/1} + days{1};
cout << format("* {:%B %Y} has ", y/m) << total_days/days{1} << " days.\n";
```

The expression `y/m/last` is the last day of the year-month pair `y/m`, and of course `y/m/1` is the first day of the month.  Both are converted to `sys_days` so that they can be subtracted to get the number of days between them.  Add 1 for the 1-based count.

**Use**

`info` can be used like this:

```
info(December/26/2019);
```

or like this:

```
info(floor<days>(system_clock::now()));
```

Here is example output:

```
26 December 2019 is a Thursday

Additional facts
* It is day number 360 of the year, 5 days left.
* It is Thursday number 52 out of 52 in 2019.
* It is Thursday number 4 out of 4 in December 2019.
* Year 2019 has 365 days.
* December 2019 has 31 days.
```

---

**Edit**

For those who are not fond of the "conventional syntax", there is a complete "constructor syntax" that can be used instead.

For example:

```
sys_days NewYears = y/1/1;
sys_days first_wd = y/1/wd[1];
sys_days last_wd = y/12/wd[last];
```

can be replaced by:

```
sys_days NewYears = year_month_day{y, month{1}, day{1}};
sys_days first_wd = year_month_weekday{y, month{1}, weekday_indexed{wd, 1}};
sys_days last_wd = year_month_weekday_last{y, month{12}, weekday_last{wd}};
```

Comment: This new abuse of the division operator is even worse than the old abuse of the bitshift operators. It makes me sad :(

Comment: On a more serious note, can I suggest that you move some of your pre-computed variables down to the sections which use them? It's a bit awkward to follow when having to scroll up and down to see where values come from and how they were generated. And you can de-clutter your day-of-year stuff a bit by doing the division first, like you did for the weeks.

Comment: Disagree completely. It looks good, it's easy to understand and, notably, it's easier to read than the more verbose version.

Comment: @CássioRenan might be, but remember that syntax abuse quite often comes with unexpected behavior. With the aforementioned bit shifts, e.g., note the behavior of `std::cout << "a*b = " << a*b << "; a^b = " << a^b << '\n';` (which is, fortunately, almost always caught at compile time, but still is an annoyance). So I'd be cautious when using this new division operator abuse.

Comment: @Ruslan Caution is always warranted with any new library.  That's why this one has been freely and publicly tested since 2015.  The feedback from clients has been incorporated back into the design.  It was not proposed for standardization until it had a solid foundation of years of positive field experience.  In particular, the use of operators has been designed with operator precedence in mind, field tested widely, and comes with an equivalent "constructor API".  See https://star-history.t9t.io/#HowardHinnant/date&google/cctz and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo .

Comment: Regarding computation of the day of the year, would an expression like `floor<days>(sd - floor<years>(sd))` also be a [correct] alternative? And would it be a viable approach, again compared to the one in the answer?

Comment: It would not give you exactly the same answer.  I've given a "calendrical computation", and your suggestion is a "chronological computation".  The difference is described for months in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018120/576911. The same analysis applies for `years` as it does for `months`.  To do calendrical arithmetic with `years` you must be using calendrical types such as `year_month_day`.  And `sys_days` is a chronological type.