# Is std::chrono::years storage really at least 17 bit?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, c++20, libc++

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

> `std::chrono::years (since C++20)
>   duration</*signed integer type of at least 17 bits*/, std::ratio<31556952>>`

Using `libc++`, it seems the underlining storage of `std::chrono::years` is `short` which is signed ***16 bits***.

```
std::chrono::years( 30797 )        // yields  32767/01/01
std::chrono::years( 30797 ) + 365d // yields -32768/01/01 apparently UB
```

Is there a typo on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) or anything else?

Example:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <chrono>

template <>
struct fmt::formatter<std::chrono::year_month_day> {
  char presentation = 'F';

  constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
    auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
    if (it != end && *it == 'F') presentation = *it++;

#   ifdef __exception
    if (it != end && *it != '}') {
      throw format_error("invalid format");
    }
#   endif

    return it;
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const std::chrono::year_month_day& ymd, FormatContext& ctx) {
    int year(ymd.year() );
    unsigned month(ymd.month() );
    unsigned day(ymd.day() );
    return format_to(
        ctx.out(),
        "{:#6}/{:#02}/{:#02}",
        year, month, day);
  }
};

using days = std::chrono::duration<int32_t, std::ratio<86400> >;
using sys_day = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<int32_t, std::ratio<86400> >>;

template<typename D>
using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, D>;
using sys_day2 = sys_time<days>;

int main()
{
  auto a = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::hours( (1<<23) - 1 ) 
      )
    )
  );

  auto b = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::minutes( (1l<<29) - 1 ) 
      )
    )
  );

  auto c = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::seconds( (1l<<35) - 1 ) 
      )
    )
  );

  auto e = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::days( (1<<25) - 1 ) 
      )
    )
  );

  auto f = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::weeks( (1<<22) - 1 ) 
      )
    )
  );

  auto g = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::months( (1<<20) - 1 ) 
      )
    )
  );

  auto h = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::years( 30797 ) // 0x7FFF - 1970
      )
    )
  );

  auto i = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_day( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::years( 30797 ) // 0x7FFF - 1970
      ) + std::chrono::days(365)
    )
  );

  fmt::print("Calendar limit by duration's underlining storage:\n"
             "23 bit hour       : {:F}\n"
             "29 bit minute     : {:F}\n"
             "35 bit second     : {:F}\n"
             "25 bit days       : {:F}\n"
             "22 bit week       : {:F}\n"
             "20 bit month      : {:F}\n"
             "16? bit year      : {:F}\n"
             "16? bit year+365d : {:F}\n"
             , a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i);
}
```

[[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/WtDaVA)]

Comment: `year` range: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal.year#members-19  `years` range:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.syn .  `year` is the "name" of the civil year and requires 16 bits.  `years` is a chrono duration, not the same thing as a `year`.  One can subtract two `year` and the result has type `years`.  `years` is required to be able to hold the result of `year::max() - year::min()`.

Comment: `std::chrono::years( 30797 ) + 365d` doesn't compile.

Comment: The result of `years{30797} + days{365}` is 204528013 with units of 216s.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, different floor duration arithmatics stuns me so bad. If not used, can we prohibit that at compile time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @HowardHinnant `years{30797} + days{365}` : Can we prohibit this at compile time?

Comment: That's just two durations being added.  To prohibit it would mean prohibiting `hours{2} + seconds{5}`.

Comment: My guess is that you're confusing calendrical components with duration types because they _do_ have such similar names.  Here's a general rule:  `duration` names are plural:  `years`, `months`, `days`.  Calendrical component names are singular:  `year`, `month`, `day`.  `year{30797} + day{365}` is a compile-time error.  `year{2020}` is this year.  `years{2020}` is a duration 2020 years long.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Would you mind please explain the inconsistency there => [SNivyp](https://godbolt.org/z/SNivyp)

Comment: I've added an answer that explains things.  If you have further questions, I'm happy to amend my answer to address them.

Answer (score 8):

The cppreference article is [correct](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.syn#def:signed_integer_type_of_at_least_17_bits). If libc++ uses a smaller type then this seems to be a bug in libc++.

Comment: But adding another `word` that probably barely used wouldn't be bulking `year_month_day` vectors unneccessarily? Could that `at least 17 bits` be not counted as norminal text?

Comment: @sandthorn `year_month_day` contains `year`, not `years`. The representation of `year` is not required to be 16-bit, although the type `short` is used as exposition. OTOH, the 17 bits part in the `years` definition is normative as it is not marked as exposition only. And frankly, saying that it ts at least 17 bits and then not requiring it is meaningless.

Comment: Ah `year` in `year_month_day` seems to be `int` indeed. => [operator int](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year/operator_int) I think this supports `at least 17 bits` `years` implementation.

Comment: Would you mind edit your answer? It turns out *std::chrono::years* is actually int and *std::chrono::year* is max at 32767 arbitarily..

Comment: @sandthorn The answer is correct, I don't see why I would need to edit it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm breaking down the example at https://godbolt.org/z/SNivyp piece by piece:

```
  auto a = std::chrono::year_month_day( 
    sys_days( 
      std::chrono::floor<days>(
        std::chrono::years(0) 
        + std::chrono::days( 365 )
      )
    )
  );
```

Simplifying and assuming `using namespace std::chrono` is in scope:

```
year_month_day a = sys_days{floor<days>(years{0} + days{365})};
```

The sub-expression `years{0}` is a `duration` with a `period` equal to `ratio<31'556'952>` and a value equal to `0`.  Note that `years{1}`, expressed as floating-point `days`, is exactly 365.2425.  This is the *average* length of the civil year.

The sub-expression `days{365}` is a `duration` with a `period` equal to `ratio<86'400>` and a value equal to `365`.

The sub-expression `years{0} + days{365}` is a `duration` with a `period` equal to `ratio<216>` and a value equal to `146'000`.  This is formed by first finding the `common_type_t` of `ratio<31'556'952>` and `ratio<86'400>` which is the GCD(31'556'952, 86'400), or 216.  The library first converts both operands to this common unit, and then does the addition in the common unit.

To convert `years{0}` to units with a period of 216s one must multiply 0 by 146'097.  This happens to be a very important point.  This conversion can easily cause overflow when done with only 32 bits.

<aside>

If at this point you feel confused, it is because the code likely intends a *calendrical* computation, but is actually doing a *chronological* computation.  Calendrical computations are computations with calendars.

Calendars have all sorts of irregularities, such as months and years being of different physical lengths in terms of days.  A calendrical computation takes these irregularities into account.

A chronological computation works with fixed units, and just cranks out the numbers without regard to calendars.  A chronological computation doesn't care if you use the Gregorian calendar, the Julian calendar, the Hindu calendar, the Chinese calendar, etc.

</aside>

Next we take our `146000[216]s` duration and convert it to a duration with a `period` of `ratio<86'400>` (which has a type-alias named `days`).  The function `floor<days>()` does this conversion and the result is `365[86400]s`, or more simply, just `365d`.

The next step takes the `duration` and converts it into a `time_point`.  The type of the `time_point` is `time_point<system_clock, days>` which has a type-alias named `sys_days`.  This is simply a count of `days` since the `system_clock` epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds.

Finally the `sys_days` is converted to a `year_month_day` with the value `1971-01-01`.

A simpler way to do this computation is:

```
year_month_day a = sys_days{} + days{365};
```

---

Consider this similar computation:

```
year_month_day j = sys_days{floor<days>(years{14699} + days{0})};
```

This results in the date `16668-12-31`.  Which is probably a day earlier than you were expecting ((14699+1970)-01-01).  The subexpression `years{14699} + days{0}` is now:  `2'147'479'803[216]s`.  Note that the run-time value is nearing `INT_MAX` (`2'147'483'647`), and that the underlying `rep` of both `years` and `days` is `int`.

Indeed if you convert `years{14700}` to units of `[216]s` you get overflow:  `-2'147'341'396[216]s`.

To fix this, switch to a calendrical computation:

```
year_month_day j = (1970y + years{14700})/1/1;
```

---

All of the results at https://godbolt.org/z/SNivyp that are adding `years` and `days` and using a value for `years` that is greater than 14699 are experiencing `int` overflow.

If one really wants to do chronological computations with `years` and `days` this way, then it would be wise to use 64 bit arithmetic.  This can be accomplished by converting `years` to units with a `rep` using greater than 32 bits early in the computation.  For example:

```
years{14700} + 0s + days{0}
```

By adding `0s` to `years`, (`seconds` must have at least 35 bits), then the `common_type` `rep` is forced to 64 bits for the first addition (`years{14700} + 0s`) and continues in 64 bits when adding `days{0}`:

```
463'887'194'400s == 14700 * 365.2425 * 86400
```

Yet another way to avoid intermediate overflow (at this range) is to truncate `years` to `days` precision *before* adding more `days`:

```
year_month_day j = sys_days{floor<days>(years{14700})} + days{0};
```

`j` has the value `16669-12-31`.  This avoids the problem because now the `[216]s` unit is never created in the first place.  And we never even get close to the limit for `years`, `days` or `year`.

Though if you were expecting `16700-01-01`, then you still have a problem, and the way to correct it is to do a calendrical computation instead:

```
year_month_day j = (1970y + years{14700})/1/1;
```

Comment: Great explanation. I am worried about the chronological computation. If I see `years{14700} + 0s + days{0}` in a codebase, I would have no idea what `0s` is doing there and how important it is. Is there an alternate, maybe more explicit way? Would something like `duration_cast<seconds>(years{14700}) + days{0}` be better?

Comment: `duration_cast` would be worse because it is bad form to use `duration_cast` for non-truncating conversions.  Truncating conversions can be a source of logic errors, and it is best to only use the "big hammer" when you need it, so that you can easily spot the truncating conversions in your code.

Comment: One could create a custom duration:  `use llyears = duration<long long, years::period>;`, and then use that instead.  But probably the best thing is to think about what you're trying to accomplish and question whether you're going about it the right way.  For example do you really need day-precision on a time scale that is 10 thousand years?  The civil calendar is only accurate to about 1 day in 4 thousand years.  Perhaps a floating point millennia would be a better unit?

Comment: Clarification:  chrono's modeling of the civil calendar is exact in the range -32767/1/1 to 32767/12/31.  The civil calendar's accuracy with respect to modeling the solar system is only about 1 day in 4 thousand years.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Between `sys_days{ years{14700} + 0s + days{1000} }` versus `sys_days{floor<days>(years{14700}) + days{1000} }` which one you prefer personally?

Comment: It would really depend on the use case and I'm currently having trouble thinking of a motivating use case to add `years` and `days`.  This is literally adding some multiple of 365.2425 days to some integral number of days.  Normally if you want to do a chronological computation on the order of months or years, it is to model some physics or biology.   Perhaps this post on the different ways to add `months` to `system_clock::time_point` would help clarify the difference between the two types of computations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018120/576911