# C++ Check Date is older than 6 month from current date

Tags: c++, date

So I have list of tutor records where it saves date join, and date terminated of them. The program will automatically delete the tutor record once they are terminated after 6 month.

So how do i check the current date is already 6 month or more since the date terminated.

I need to input date join and date terminated.

Comment: If you were given a date, how would you work out - on paper - if today's date is more than six months after that date?

Comment: For example the date terminated is 02-09-2019, then I compare today and the date terminated already past 6 months or more. If already past, the program shall delete the tutor records.

Comment: @RichardTiozard: you don't understand Peter's question: it's not about what you would do once you have determined the date difference. It's about the calculation itself. Let me give you an example: from Jan. 2 to July 2, that's 182 days and from March 2 to Sep. 2, it's 184, so you cannot use the amount of days. You need to compare the years, the months, and the days. How will you do this?

Comment: I'm not that sure but I think by using array {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}. For example if we want to check March 2 to Sep 2, then loop from array[4] value increment until array[10]. and get how many days. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to C++20, use a date/time library such as [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) (works back to C++11).

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

date::year_month_day
current_date()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_time zt{current_zone(), system_clock::now()};
    return year_month_day{floor<days>(zt.get_local_time())};
}

struct tutor_record
{
    date::year_month_day joined;
    date::year_month_day terminated;
};

void
trim(std::list<tutor_record>& records)
{
    using namespace date;
    auto limit = current_date() - months{6};
    if (!limit.ok())
        limit = limit.year()/limit.month()/last;
    records.remove_if([limit](auto const& t) {return t.terminated <= limit;});
}
```

- Define a function for getting the current (presumably local) date.
- Define a data structure to hold the information.
- Get the current date and perform a calendrical computation to subtract 6 months ([see this answer for contrasting with chronological computations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018120/576911)).
- Traverse the list and remove the unwanted items.

This will port to C++20 by:

- Remove `#include "date/tz.h"`.
- Remove `using namespace date;`.
- Change `date::` to `std::chrono::`.

*Remarks:*

- Works with leap years.
- Doesn't require explicit low-level knowledge of how to do calendrical computations.
- If the current date in UTC is sufficient, this program can be simplified by
  the use of the header-only library [`"date/date.h"`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which does not require the use of time zones.

  `return floor<days>(system_clock::now());`

Answer (score 1):

c++20 concept code

```
#include <chrono>

auto then = year_month_day(tutor.join);
auto current = year_month_day(time.now());
auto diff = current - then;
if (diff >= year_month_day(0,6,0))
  delete_tutor(tutor);
```