# C++ Subtracting days from current time using date.h

Tags: c++, date

I am trying to subtract a number of days from the current time using the `date.h` library of Howard Hinnant.

```
auto currentTime()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return date::floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
}

auto oldDate(date::days daysNum)
{
    using namespace date;
    auto time = currentTime();
    auto sd = floor<days>(time);
    auto time_of_day = time - sd;
    auto ymd = year_month_day{sd} - daysNum;
    if (!ymd.ok())
        ymd = ymd.year()/ymd.month()/last;
    return sys_days{ymd} + time_of_day;
}

int main(){
    oldDate(date::days{10});
    return 0;
}
```

However, the compiler complains about `auto ymd = year_month_day{sd} - daysNum;`. The error is:

```
no match for `operator-` (operand types are `date::year_month_day` and `date::days {aka std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> >}`)
```

Could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year_month_day` is the wrong data structure for days-oriented arithmetic.  The reason is that doing so [results in gratuitously expensive code](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/FAQ#day_arithmetic) (like putting an indexing operator on `std::list`).

The right data structure is just a `time_point`.  This makes your `oldDate` function really simple *and* very efficient:

```
auto oldDate(date::days daysNum)
{
    return currentTime() - daysNum;
}
```

If you were doing [calendrical arithmetic with months or years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018120/576911), then your original code is the right idea.